# Why can people edit my stuff, and why can't I delete comments on my question?

Tags: discussion, edits, etiquette

I asked a question on a Stack Exchange site. I edited it after a while, thinking that I might have given too much information away. This one guy checked out the edits to my question and posted the info back! I couldn't do anything about it!

I can't even delete his comment because I have no "right" to do stuff to my own question. I mean I edited my post because I had a reason to do so, but this guy comes out of nowhere and posts that edited part again... and in bold letters, too!

---

Why can people edit my stuff, and why can't I delete comments on my question?

Comment: Can you link the question you're referring to? It will make analysis of the situation a lot easier.

Comment: nope I cant..don't wanna attract attention to that anymore..lol

Comment: I edited your question, let me know if it is what you were looking for.

Comment: btw..why the downvotes ? what did I ask ? lol ..why's everyone so serious on SO ? :)

Comment: @jjguy :: huh ? Which ques did you edit ? ur not the one who posted my DELETED info back..its someone else

Comment: @Happy, I edited this question.

Comment: This question presumably? http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/8495/trying-to-run-some-3d-game-but-its-giving-an-error-even-though-i-have-the-latest

Comment: @Martin :: Awesome!..thanks! :| lol..why did I even ask..anyways..

Comment: There's nothing wrong with playing second life, don't be ashamed

Comment: @Downvoter :: So u downvoted my ques..huh ? just kidding :P When did I ever say that I am ashamed ? lol..SL is one awesome game!

Comment: @Happy: I (and possibly also others) downvoted it because the question was unclear (as suggested by the downvote tooltip). Now, since someone has edited it to translate some odd variant of English into more formal English, I started to understand the question and hence I removed the downvote :) (look, that's another benefit of others being able to edit your questions, it's just all to improve them)

Comment: @BalusC :: ohh my English was unreadable ? Sorry about that :P

Comment: Try to overcome [smart](http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html), not like a disrespectful kid :)

Comment: @BalusC :: Thanks for the advice :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq), not my words:

> #### Other people can edit my stuff?!
>
> Like Wikipedia, this site is collaboratively edited, and all edits are tracked. If you are not comfortable with the idea of your questions and answers being edited by other trusted users, this may not be the site for you.

Comment: don't have no problem with anyone editting or whatever..just don't post back stuff I DELETED! asking for too much am I ?

Comment: @Happy, well, it would be really hard to distinguish the difference between a plain old edit, and adding back deleted content.  Besides, to make that question have any relevance to other people, the deleted information was probably necessary.

Comment: @Happy, If you really want something deleted, flag it for a moderator.  They can delete stuff for you.

Comment: yeah ok..got it..thnx all

Comment: nah..I didn't REALLy wanted it deleted..doesnt matter anyways..I was like why would u post back something I removed..anyways..cant do much abt it ..now can I?

Comment: Because the content is cc-wiki though it can also end up on a variety of other web sites. Best solution is to not post up stuff you don't want public in the first place.

Comment: @Martin : ok..thnx for the info..it was no big deal..just didn't like the idea of anyone posting back stuff I removed from my own question

Comment: @Happy, usually people won't add stuff back that you delete unless they feel that it was important for the question.

Comment: @jjnguy :: yep..right..btw..how do I find out who corrected the grammar of my this question..lol ..I really wanna know :P

Comment: @Happy, it was me. You can find out by looking at the user card to the left of your own, or by clicking the time period in "edited [time period] ago."

Comment: ah ok..thnx..I am not very good at writing formal English especially when it comes to forums like these :)

Comment: @Pop, see @Happy's comment above (should have been directed at you)

Comment: @jjnguy, thanks. You're welcome, Happy.