# Why was an edit to my question accepted without my knowledge?

Tags: discussion, edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why can people edit my stuff, and why can't I delete comments on my question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68356/why-can-people-edit-my-stuff-and-why-cant-i-delete-comments-on-my-question)

Why did the system accept and effect [an edit to my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10905053/how-to-show-indeterminate-progress-bar-when-refresh-button-is-pressed-in-actionb) that was submitted without my knowledge?

Comment: You should have gotten a sky blue notification up in your global inbox.

Comment: is this the question you ask about? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10905053/how-to-show-indeterminate-progress-bar-when-refresh-button-is-pressed-in-actionb - and the edit you refer to, is it a [rollback done in rev 3](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/10905053/3)?

Comment: @darkcrow: quite the stretch on your "government department of corrupt country" analogy. You either have (1) no clue who works for Stackoverflow and who does not (2) no clue what a government is, or (3) no clue what corruption is. We can help with your question, but it would be nice if you left out unrelated analogies.

Comment: Even though this question is closed, you have a different *legitimate* question, which is "is it appropriate to add an additional requirement to my question and offer a bounty to reward those who meet the additional requirement?"

Comment: Hi @darkcrow, sorry to have caught you off guard with my edit.  I was trying to be fair to anadobes who offered not one, but two answers to your question.  Answering a question only to have the asker add additional requirements is the sort of scope creep that I think all software developers try to avoid.  As I said in my comment, there's no reason that your second question can't stand on its own independently, so I encourage you to ask it as a separate question.  It's better than a combo-question and will probably get better answers.

Comment: @blahdiblah Most politely. Anadobes answer was very good one. I +1 it but was incomplete. I would say you assumed that answer is complete and I am asking for an additional requirement. The update was part of initial question and in any case another question would have to have everything from this question. If you look at the broader purpose of SO it is help from one developer to another, good help, health help and that is what we were doing there.

Comment: *Stackoverflow suddenly looks like a government department of corrupt country.* How do I express rolling eyes using emoticons?

Comment: Ok, I take my words back. Sorry everyone.

Comment: @gnat Yes. I tried to answer you several times, it was not taking my comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#editing):

> **Eeeeek! Other people can edit my posts?!**
>
> All contributions are licensed under Creative Commons and this site is collaboratively edited, like Wikipedia. If you see something that needs improvement, click edit and help us make it so!
>
> All edits are tracked in a public revision history. To view revisions, click the edit date on the post.

From your talking about "accepted" edits I assume you are referring to the "suggested edits" feature. This feature allows users with less than 2000 reputation point to suggest edits that have to be accepted first. Users with more than 2000 reputation points can freely edit questions without having to wait for acceptance.

Comment: My most polite request is to rethink about. Whatever time I have spend at SO. I feel it is place for developers to help each other and stop bad people from spoiling it but someone just did very bad thing to my question.

Comment: @dark editing questions to mean something *entirely new* isn't really how Stack Overflow works. The normal course of action would be starting a new question. I assume blahdiblah felt the same way

Comment: Most politely the answer is incomplete till we have an `Indeterminate ProgressBar` which looks same as in ICS. blahdiblah did not contribute to the answer, neither he left any pointer for use to work towards the answer whereas anadobes who answered the question earlier contributed with another answer without any objection.

Comment: Looks like blahdiblah has answered 224 question non related to Android.

Comment: @darkcrow as said, updating questions like that is not really how Stack Overflow works. blahdiblah edited your question and politely pointed you towards how to solve the situation properly. I understand you didn't mean any harm, but neither did he. If you got your answer, I think you can just put the issue to rest.